# I cant solve com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jdbc

I hope you will not mark it as duplicate cause I checked a lot of posts answers without having  any solution to my problem .. I can't excecute my Insert statment, It's like ginving me a null object of operator, when I set my attributs as a null in defaut it insert it succefuly as a null object in the database

This is my entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="operators")
public class Operator {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer id;
private String opName;
private String opCountry;
private Date opDate;
private Integer opMCC;
private Integer opCC;
private Integer opMNC;
private Integer opNC;
private String opPMN;
private String opDNS;
private String opAPN;
private String opMails; 
private String opNums;
private String Comment;

public String getOpName() {
    return opName;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public void setOpName(String opName) {
    this.opName = opName;
}
public String getOpCountry() {
    return opCountry;
}
public void setOpCountry(String opCountry) {
    this.opCountry = opCountry;
}
public Date getOpDate() {
    return opDate;
}
public void setOpDate(Date opDate) {
    this.opDate = opDate;
}
public Integer getOpMCC() {
    return opMCC;
}
public void setOpMCC(Integer opMCC) {
    this.opMCC = opMCC;
}
public Integer getOpCC() {
    return opCC;
}
public void setOpCC(Integer opCC) {
    this.opCC = opCC;
}
public Integer getOpMNC() {
    return opMNC;
}
public void setOpMNC(Integer opMNC) {
    this.opMNC = opMNC;
}
public Integer getOpNC() {
    return opNC;
}
public void setOpNC(Integer opNC) {
    this.opNC = opNC;
}
public String getOpPMN() {
    return opPMN;
}
public void setOpPMN(String opPMN) {
    this.opPMN = opPMN;
}
public String getOpDNS() {
    return opDNS;
}
public void setOpDNS(String opDNS) {
    this.opDNS = opDNS;
}
public String getOpAPN() {
    return opAPN;
}
public void setOpAPN(String opAPN) {
    this.opAPN = opAPN;
}
public String getOpMails() {
    return opMails;
}
public void setOpMails(String opMails) {
    this.opMails = opMails;
}
public String getOpNums() {
    return opNums;
}
public void setOpNums(String opNums) {
    this.opNums = opNums;
}

public String getComment() {
    return Comment;
}
public void setComment(String comment) {
    Comment = comment;
}
```

}

This my Add view :

```
<form  method="POST" commandName="operator" id="form-banner" class="form-horizontal" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/operator/add.html">

          <div class="form-group">
             <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-banner-name">ID/Name Operator</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="Name Operator" class="form-control" path="opName" required/>           
              </div>   

          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-banner-name">Country</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" name="country" value="" placeholder="Country" class="form-control" path="opCountry" required/>           
              </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-banner-name">Date of Database</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" name="date" value="" placeholder="Date" class="form-control" path="opDate" required/>
              </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-banner-name">Operator MCC</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="MCC"  class="form-control"  path="opMCC" required/>
              </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-banner-name">Operator CC</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" name="cc" value="" placeholder="CC"  class="form-control" path="opCC" required/>
              </div>
          </div>

         <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-banner-name">Operator MNC</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" name="mnc" value=""  placeholder="MNC"  class="form-control" path="opMNC" required/>
              </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-banner-name">Operator NC</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" name="cc" value="" placeholder="NC"  class="form-control" path="opNC" required/>
              </div>
          </div>

        <div class="form-group">
               <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-banner-name">PMN</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10" >
              <textarea placeholder="PMN" class="form-control" rows="3" path="opPMN" required></textarea>
              </div>
        </div>

          <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-banner-name">DNS</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
              <textarea placeholder="DNS" class="form-control" rows="3" path="opDNS" required></textarea>
              </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-banner-name">APN</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
              <textarea placeholder="APN" class="form-control" rows="3" path="opAPN" required></textarea>
              </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-banner-name">Mails</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
              <textarea placeholder="Address Mails" class="form-control" rows="3" path="opMails" required></textarea>
              </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-banner-name">Phones</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
              <textarea placeholder="Phone Numbers" class="form-control" rows="3" path="opNums" required></textarea>
              </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-banner-name">Comments</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
              <textarea placeholder="Put your comment" class="form-control" rows="3" path="Comment" required></textarea>
              </div>
          </div>

         <input class="button-primary" type="submit" value="Add"> 

          </form>
```

This is the exception I faced and couldn't solve it.

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:948)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
cause mère

org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:74)
    org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:136)
    org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:96)
    org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:58)
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2966)
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3477)
    org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81)
    org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:362)
    org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:203)
    org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:183)
    org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:167)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:321)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:286)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:192)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:204)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:55)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:189)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:49)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:763)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:755)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:751)
    com.roaming.dao.OperatorDAOImpl.addOperator(OperatorDAOImpl.java:63)
    com.roaming.service.OpServiceImpl.addOperator(OpServiceImpl.java:21)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy30.addOperator(Unknown Source)
    com.roaming.controller.OperatorController.addingOperator(OperatorController.java:37)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
cause mère

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'opAPN' cannot be null
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1040)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4074)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4006)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2468)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2629)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2719)
    com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
    com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2450)
    com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2371)
    com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2355)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:133)
    org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:96)
    org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:58)
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2966)
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3477)
    org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81)
    org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:362)
    org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:203)
    org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:183)
    org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:167)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:321)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:286)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:192)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:204)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:55)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:189)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:49)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:763)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:755)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:751)
    com.roaming.dao.OperatorDAOImpl.addOperator(OperatorDAOImpl.java:63)
    com.roaming.service.OpServiceImpl.addOperator(OpServiceImpl.java:21)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy30.addOperator(Unknown Source)
    com.roaming.controller.OperatorController.addingOperator(OperatorController.java:37)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

It saif that tha column 'opAPN' cannot be null but when I set it at null in my database it pass to the other column and inject me the same exception..etc

Comment: I suggest removing not null constraint from DB table schema. This should solve your problem. Or you can explicitly set opAPN to some default value 0 before persisting if it is null.

Comment: if I set my attribute to 0 value it insert it as a 0 value .. and if I initialize it. It take me to initialize the others and after that the data is stored between null and 0

Comment: there is any help please :(

Comment: execute 'desc workflow;' in mysql and post the output i.e. schema of your table.

Comment: This is the schema of my table